# Extract a part of string with complex pattern SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, function, wildcard

I am working with string as below:

```
DOT LTB TOL SP BLM 3X(35X**25.1**GR)BWY BNL
```

And I am trying to extract the float between the last `X` and `G` -> `25.1`.

In Python it is an easy task using regex expression: `**[0-9]+X([0-9\.]+)G**`

But I could not find a way to extract the data here in SQL Server:

I tried to write a function that define the position of X and the `)` argument like that:

```
AS
Begin

    Declare @LastX as INT
    Declare @LastG as INT
    Declare @Diff as INT
    Declare @Result as varchar(50)
    Set @LastX = LEN(@Temp) - CAST(CHARINDEX('X', REVERSE(@Temp)) AS Integer) 
    Set @LastG = LEN(@Temp) - CAST(CHARINDEX(')', REVERSE(@Temp)) AS Integer)
    Set @Diff = @LastG - @LastX
    IF @Diff > 0
        Set @Result = SUBSTRING(@Temp, @LastX, @Diff)
    ELSE
        Set @Result = 0
    
    Return @Result
End
```

My result is `5X25.1G`

Can you help me with this?

I'm also open if you have other suggestion to extract this value in SQL.

Comment: Hint, you want `PATINDEX` for finding the position of patterns, not `CHARINDEX` which finds the position of characters.

Comment: In newer versions of sql server you can also execute a python script

Comment: perhaps this may help (?<=X)(\d+.\d+),   I don't know whether positive look behind is supported in sql-server or not

Comment: @Larnu It works much better this `PATINDEX` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's *always* between the last `X` and last `G`, you could use a couple of `CHARINDEX`'s as you have tried. I prefer to do this in the `FROM` and use `APPLY` to avoid repetition of code and a "nasty" long single expression:

```sql
SELECT *,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(R.YourString,CI1.I+1,CI2.I-CI1.I-1))
FROM (VALUES('DOT LTB TOL SP BLM 3X(35X25.1GR)BWY BNL'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(REVERSE(V.YourString)))R(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('G',R.YourString),0)))CI1(I)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('X',R.YourString,CI1.I),0)))CI2(I)
```

*That* really *long expression would be the following, by the way:*

```sql
SELECT V.Yourstring,
       REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(V.YourString),NULLIF(CHARINDEX('G',REVERSE(V.YourString)),0)+1,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('X',REVERSE(V.YourString),NULLIF(CHARINDEX('G',REVERSE(V.YourString)),0)),0)-NULLIF(CHARINDEX('G',REVERSE(V.YourString)),0)-1))
FROM (VALUES('DOT LTB TOL SP BLM 3X(35X25.1GR)BWY BNL'))V(YourString)
```

*Have fun trying to read that. Hence why the `APPLY`s.*

Comment: Takes time to understand ;) works perfectly thx a lot !

Comment: You're welcome, @GabinLegrand . If it does answer the question, please do consider marking it as the solution, so that future readers know it was helpful. Thanks.